# Quiz with shuffle, images and sound

Tags: javascript, html, audio

I've recently started coding, and I'm trying to make a quiz!
The quiz is about different bands and artists.
But, with the code I got now, I am unable to `shuffle` the questions. How do I make them appear in a `random order`?
Also, instead of ending the quiz at the last question and giving you correct/incorrect answers, how can I make it so it instead it plays a sound to tell the user if correct or incorrect. Explained differently, the quiz loops with 3 questions, but they come 1 at the time in a shuffled order.

Another thing I'm trying to change is; how do I make it so I can have an image as a background for each individual question, example: what band is this, with cold play as background.

IF anything seems unclear or too broad, please ask and I'll do my best to enlighten you.

**HTML:**

```
<h2 id="test_status"></h2>
<h2> Hvilket band er dette? </h2>
<div id="test"></div>
```

**SCRIPT:**

```
var pos = 0, test, test_status, question, choice, choices, chA, chB, chC, chD, chE, correct = 0;
var questions = [
    [ "Hvilket band er dette?", "Linkin Park", "Green Day", "Coldplay", "Billy Talent", "Hollywoodundead" ,"B" ],
    [ "Hvilket band har denne sangen?", "Linkin Park", "Green Day", "Coldplay", "Billy Talent", "Hollywoodundead" ,"A" ],
    [ "Hvilket band er dette?", "Linkin Park", "Green Day", "Coldplay", "Billy Talent", "Hollywoodundead" ,"B" ],


];
function _(x){
    return document.getElementById(x);
}    
function renderQuestion(){
    test = _("test");
    if(pos >= questions.length){
        test.innerHTML = "<h2>Du fikk "+correct+" av "+questions.length+" spørsmål riktige</h2>";
        _("test_status").innerHTML = "Quiz fullført";
        pos = 0;
        correct = 0;
        return false;
    }
    _("test_status").innerHTML = "Spørsmål "+(pos+1)+" av "+questions.length;
    question = questions[pos][0];
    chA = questions[pos][1];
    chB = questions[pos][2];
    chC = questions[pos][3];
    chD = questions[pos][4];
    chE = questions[pos][5];
    test.innerHTML = "<h3>"+question+"</h3>";
    test.innerHTML += "<input type='radio' name='choices' value='A'> "+chA+"<br>";
    test.innerHTML += "<input type='radio' name='choices' value='B'> "+chB+"<br>";
    test.innerHTML += "<input type='radio' name='choices' value='C'> "+chC+"<br>";
    test.innerHTML += "<input type='radio' name='choices' value='D'> "+chD+"<br>";
    test.innerHTML += "<input type='radio' name='choices' value='E'> "+chE+"<br><br>";
    test.innerHTML += "<button onclick='checkAnswer()'>Neste</button>";
}
function checkAnswer(){
    choices = document.getElementsByName("choices");
    for(var i=0; i<choices.length; i++){
        if(choices[i].checked){
            choice = choices[i].value;
        }
    }
    if(choice == questions[pos][5]){
        correct++;
    }
    pos++;
    renderQuestion();
}
window.addEventListener("load", renderQuestion, false);
```

**JSFIDDLE:**

https://jsfiddle.net/cxjth78k/

Comment: use `Math.random()`

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, but where do I put the command?

Comment: I found better option use https://github.com/coolaj86/knuth-shuffle
to shuffle the array `questions` and then use `for (... in ...)` to get each element

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to randomize (shuffle) a JavaScript array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2450954/how-to-randomize-shuffle-a-javascript-array)